# What is a symbolized call stack?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, chromium-embedded

I have been working on an application(Windows) on Visual Studio 2010 and encountered a crash. So for the same i asked for help from an expert and he asked me to submit a symbolized call stack of crash. Can anyone explain me what exactly is this symbolized call stack and how to get that from VS. The application i am building is using CEF(Chromium embedded framework). I have downloaded binaries and modifying it to my needs.

Comment: Both  answers are best but selected first one as it helped me in one more question which i was about to ask. Thank you both for your answers, i am very much thankful to you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think he is asking for a call stack with symbols available (as opposed to just call offsets like this - libcef.dll!11357796() Unknown).

Assuming you are developing with a binary distribution of CEF, go back to https://cefbuilds.com/ and find the distribution you used and the exact build number.  At the end of the row you will see an additional link for Debug or Release Symbols.  Download these and unzip them if zipped.

Now go back to your Visual Studio project, run until you hit your crash.  Double click one of the unresolved symbols like "libcef.dll!11357796()    Unknown".  You will get a dialog asking you to locate the debug symbol file.  Navigate to where you extracted the pdb files in the previous step, and it should find the symbols.  It will then try to load the source file, which you don't have unless you downloaded CEF and Chromium sources, but you don't need that for a symbolic stack track.  Just cancel and in your call stack you should now see symbols for all of libcef.  Copy and paste and pass on to the person helping you.

Comment: Can i do same if i directly run executable, without clicking run/debug on visual studio project. I mean if i run executable from out folder created when i build VS project.

Comment: Yes, you should.  Windows will probably offer to launch the debugger.  Do so, and you should be able to continue as above, except it won't know where your source is yet.  If it is hung and Windows hasn't asked if you want to debug, you can launch Visual Studio and from the Debug menu select "Attach to Process...", select your process from the list presented, and then pause the debugger to see what is going on.  Keep in mind that CEF is multi-process, though probably you want to examine the main process.  You can also try debugging with --single-process on the command line.

Comment: Yea had figured out the same, anyway thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

It's one that has function names (and ideally filenames and line numbers) rather than plain hex addresses.

If you have debug symbols for your build, the call stack you get in the Visual Studio debugger's Call Stack window should be symbolized.